# How to filter very small values in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a large dataset in which one column is p-values that range from 0.9 to being extremely small like 5e-79. In R I can sort the data in descending order and see the smallest values are there and in scientific notation.

I am just trying to filter the values to get only those smaller than 0.00000005. However, any line I try for filtering does not actually filter out the large p-values.

For example I am trying:

```
pval <- select(df, pvalue)
pval <- filter(pval, pvalue < 5e-8)

#or:
pval <- select(df, pvalue)
pval <- pval[pval$pvalue < 0.0000005]
```

When I view the head of my `pval` output I am getting:

```
head(pval)
pvalue
1:  0.954
2:  0.787
3:  0.837
4:  0.629
5:  0.422
6:  0.422
```

The total number of rows does change from `df` to `pvalue` (35568235 to 35503455 rows) but I can see the filter isn't removing all the rows I expect it to.

What can cause this and what can I do to fix it? As there's no error message and I haven't found similar enough questions I'm not sure where to start - any help is appreciated.

I've tried running this with some example data which also seems to have the same problem:

```
pval <- structure(list(pvalue = c("5.00E-72", "1.40E-78", "0.9", "0.5", 
"56-e23", "1-e8")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: It appears your p-values are character/string values rather than numbers. Do you know how they became character values? There's probably a problem earlier in the pipeline that is causing the real issue.

Comment: Apart from them being characters like @MrFlick says, some values are not written properly. 56-e23 should be corrected to 56E-23 as well as 1-e8. If they are real values from your dataset, something went wrong

Comment: The correct dataset should be `pval <- structure(list(pvalue = as.numeric(c("5.00e-72", "1.4e-78", "0.9", "0.5", 
                                  "56e-23", "1e-8"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                        "data.frame"))`, unless this is how your data actually are presented, in which case the question should be geared towards cleaning it up.

Comment: The example is one I quickly typed up - but adding ```as.numeric``` to my real data has worked - thank you for your comments!

Comment: FYI, cleaning up your data with `as.numeric` in this case is almost certainly a *lossy* operation. How relevant the loss of information is depends on what you're using the numbers for, and how close they are to your thresholds. For instance, `"0.9"` might really be `0.859` round up and string-ified, which can be a significant difference in some use-cases. I recommend that you not patch the *symptom* by converting back to numbers, you should instead go back into your project and find where things shifted from number-like to string-like, and then change *that* code.

Comment: Said differently, while I recognize this may not be a dissertation (though it does not change my thought here if it is), but if I were reviewing a journal submission and I noticed that code used in the evaluation was converting numbers to strings and back like this, whether unknowing or uncaring, I would likely push it back as suspect. There are several things that can go wrong in that conversion back and forth, loss of accuracy and precision being just two of them.

Comment: That is completely understandable and I appreciate you going through the details of the function's issues. Thank you for this, I will make sure to be aware of this issue and start troubleshooting from the source for any future work (for this case I have downloaded the data and don't have a point of contact for who generated it and the p-value filter is the first step that I code, if there's another way I can more properly format it please let me know, I've seen I can change ```options(digits)``` but I'm not experienced in coding so I'm not sure what's the best solution).